# Pedometers / fitness trackers and setting stride length from your height - how accurate?

Tags: physiology, mathematics

Looking at a couple of pedometer instruction leaflets, from different manufacturers, and spotted that they both suggest you can approximate your stride length from your height via the following formula:

> females = 0.413 * height
>
> males = 0.415 * height

Are these formula accurate, as they don't account for leg length or weight?

The formula not only appear in numerous instruction booklets but on numerous sites eg.

- [Soleus: determing your stride (instruction manual)](https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0196/4616/files/Soleus-determing_your_stride.pdf)
- [NL 1000 Users Guide](http://www.new-lifestyles.com/NL-1000_Users_Guide.pdf)
- [Oregon Scientific SE900 User's Manual Page 3](http://www.manualguru.com/oregon-scientific/se900/users-manual/page-3)
- [Walking With attitude: How to Measure Stride or Step Length for your Pedometer](https://www.walkingwithattitude.com/articles/features/how-to-measure-stride-or-step-length-for-your-pedometer)
- [Live Healthy: How to Determine Stride for a Pedometer by Height & Weight](http://livehealthy.chron.com/determine-stride-pedometer-height-weight-4518.html)
- [Body Trainers Reviews: How to Determine Stride Length for an Elliptical Machine](http://bodytrainersreviews.com/how-to-determine-stride-length-for-an-elliptical-machine)

Comment: I'm looking for the claim you doubt, that we can investigate. Is it that the quoted formulae are accurate? You answered that yourself. Is it the Daily Mail claim that pedometers disagree with each other by 40%? That's fine, but likely unrelated to the formula.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.  This isn't a general "ask any question" site. According to the [FAQ](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/faq#questions), Skeptics.SE is for researching the evidence behind the claims you hear or read. The claim here appears to be "the formulae provided in the manuals is accurate". (You should quote more of the manuals so we can see if they are actually claiming this, or merely suggesting an approximation.) You have already refuted this claim in the question; there is no more for an answerer to do (in the scope of Skeptics.SE).

Comment: Removed my half researched findings, I hope this sufficiently vanilla for you to unleash it on the masses.

Comment: Thanks for your sarcasm, but please note that most of your sources explain it is NOT ACCURATE. It appears that nobody is making the claim that these estimates are particularly accurate, so there is no claim to respond to.

Comment: Meanwhile, the answer to your question is provided in the paper [you yourself quoted](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=U2G_4FirSNIC&pg=PA163&lpg=PA163&dq=stride+length+is+determined+mainly+by+the+person%E2%80%99s+stature,+weight,&source=bl&ots=hW4t6RhnFQ&sig=pJPQe_jLDOSbrpEB3mb6WN2d6Kc&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=stride%20length%20is%20determined%20mainly%20by%20the%20person%E2%80%99s%20stature%2C%20weight%2C&f=false)